# multibib and notes.bib files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, notes

I'm using the `multibib` package with pdflatex to create multiple bibliographies in an article. I'm using a bibtex file `lit.bib` which contains all my bibliography entries.

`article.tex` looks like this:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pri}{Bib1}
\newcites{sec}{Bib2}

\begin{document}

\begin{section}
...some text including citations..\citepri{sometag1}...\citepri{sometag2}

\bibliographypri{lit.bib}
\bibliographystylepri{apsrev4-1}

\end{section}

\begin{section}
...more text including citations..\citesec{sometag3}...\citepri{sometag2}... \citesec{sometag4}

\bibliographysec{lit.bib}
\bibliographystylesec{apsrev4-1}

\end{section}

\end{document}
```

Then I proceed:

```
pdflatex article.tex
bibtex pri
bibtex sec
pdflatex article.tex
pdflatex article.tex
```

The Problem is, that in the aux files (`pri.aux`, `sec.aux`) I have a line

```
 \bibdata{priNotes, lit.bib}
```

respectively

```
 \bibdata{secNotes, lit.bib}
```

where the files `priNotes.bib` and `secNotes.bib` are not created in the first step. I only receive a file `articleNotes.bib`.
I can change this manually in the aux files (remove `priNotes`, or rename `articleNotes.bib` to `preNotes.bib` and `secNotes.bib`) and everything works fine, but I'm looking for an "elegant" solution for this problem.
What do I have to do to create this 2 different Notes files in the first step?

Comment: How `preNotes.bib` and `secNotes.bib` ar generated? I mean from where?

Comment: in the step 'pdflatex article.tex' the file 'articleNotes.bib' is created. I want to create the files 'priNotes.bib' and 'secNotes.bib' instead, because in the step 'bibtex pri.aux' those files are required.